# Query returning false

Tags: php, mysql

I have been stuck on this for the past 2 hours and can't see what the problem is here.

When I execute the SQL in phpmyadmin manually it runs fine when i substitute `:item_quant` and `:item_code` for their true values.

When adding an echo on return false to see if `$item_quant` and `$item_code` are the correct values it shows them as the correct values.

```
$sql = "UPDATE inventory SET item_quant=item_quant+:item_quant WHERE item_code=':item_code' LIMIT 1";
    $query = $database->prepare($sql);
    $result = $query->execute(array(':item_quant' => $item_quant, ':item_code' => $item_code));

    if ($result) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Any help or insight as to why this would be failing would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placeholders must not be put inside quotes.

```
$sql = "UPDATE inventory SET item_quant=item_quant+:item_quant WHERE item_code=:item_code LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Still get the same outcome. when entering manually in phpmyadmin because it is a VARCHAR column it needs quotes else it won't run.

EDIT: Tried this again and it worked.. I have no idea... Shoot me please.

Comment: That's correct, you need quotes when doing it manually, but placeholders take care of that automatically.

Comment: @BradleyScott: Yes, if you *manually* run the query, you need quotes around strings.  When using prepared statements, you don't quote the placeholders.  The values will be interpreted as strings when you run the query.

Comment: @BradleyScott If it's returning `false` then you're getting an error. What is the error message? You should enable PDO error handling: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: @Barmar I tried this before I had use "htmlentites" on the post values. This returned false. I then added the quotes returned false. Added htmlentites returned false. Posted this question. Removed quotes and kept htmlentites, returned true. 

Long story short I'm a moron lol.

Comment: You shouldn't be storing html entities in the database. Store the raw data, and use `htmlentities` when displaying on a web page.

Comment: @Barmar that's what i mean't i wasn't using it on the webpage to display the `item_code` in an `<option>` so when it was receiving the value after post it wasn't getting the raw data.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quotations:

```
$sql = "UPDATE inventory SET item_quant=item_quant+:item_quant WHERE item_code=:item_code LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Still get the same outcome. when entering manually in phpmyadmin because it is a VARCHAR column it needs quotes else it won't run.

EDIT: Tried this again and it worked.. I have no idea... Shoot me please.